# Storing Pubnub data in mysql

Tags: python, mysql, iot, pubnub

Concept:

Sending GPS data and proximity data over a pubnub channel to store them in a mysql database to then monitor the database content with grafana.

Current situation:

We have 2 people publishing data over a pubnub channel named 'frameData', one sending the GPS data and the other sending the proximity data. The echo gives the correct parameters, however they don't get published to the database. Can anyone help solving this problem?

Code:

```
import os
import time
import sys
import datetime
 
import MySQLdb
 
from pubnub.enums import PNStatusCategory
from pubnub.callbacks import SubscribeCallback
from pubnub.pnconfiguration import PNConfiguration
from pubnub.pubnub import PubNub
 

# removed the pub and sub key for the purpose of asking this question
pnconfig = PNConfiguration()
pnconfig.publish_key = "pub-c-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
pnconfig.subscribe_key = "sub-c-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
pubnub = PubNub(pnconfig)
 
CHANNEL = "frameData"
 
database = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="pi", passwd="raspberry",db="IoTProject")
cursor = database.cursor()
 
FrameID = 1
SerieNummer = "000001"
Longitude = ""
Latitude = ""
isGeladen = ""
Datum=datetime.datetime.now()
 
class MySubscribeCallbackITF(SubscribeCallback):
    def message (self, pubnub, message):
 
        if type(message.message) is list:
 
            Latitude = message.message[0].lstrip("u")
            Longitude = message.message[1].lstrip("u")
            print(Latitude)
            print(Longitude)
            return(Latitude,Longitude)
 
        elif type(message.message) is not  list:
 
            isGeladen = message.message
            print(isGeladen)
            return(isGeladen)

        else:
 
            print("No data available")
 

    def presence(self, pubnub, event):
            print("[PRESENCE: {​​​​}​​​​]".format(event.event))
            print("uuid: {​​​​}​​​​, channel: {​​​​}​​​​".format(event.uuid, event.channel))
 
    def status(self, pubnub, event):
            if event.category == PNStatusCategory.PNConnectedCategory:
                    print("[STATUS: PNConnectedCategory]")
                    print("connected to channels: " + CHANNEL)
 

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO IoTProject(FrameID,SerieNummer,isGeladen,Longitude,Latitude,Datum) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",(FrameID,SerieNummer,isGeladen,Longitude,Latitude,Datum))
database.commit()
 
print('Listening...')
 
pubnub.add_listener(MySubscribeCallbackITF())
pubnub.subscribe().channels(CHANNEL).execute()
```

Output:
[Data that gets placed in the database so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NstOH.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide any logs you have from your `print` statements. And if you can [enable PubNub SDK logging](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/python/pubnub-python-sdk-troubleshooting-guide) and reproduce, that would be helpful. And what are you `return`ing to in the `message` callback. There shouldn't be anything to "return to" since this is an async call. Are you getting any errors? Also, how fast are the publishers sending messages (messages/minute).

Comment: As I reread the details, it appears you are receiving the messages in your `message` callback but the messages are not getting to your database. Again, any errors being reported around `cursor.execute`?

Comment: I have enabled the PubNub SDK, the image below shows feedback, I censored the longitude and latitude out. You're right, the return from the message callback is removed now. Data sends around every 5 seconds for the GPS module and around 10 seconds if value changes from previous value. So esstimate 15 messages/minute.

Screenshot below: (Didn't really see how to add a screenshot as a response so I made a link to the image)

https://ibb.co/YtWzpPV

@CraigConover

Comment: How would you be able to receive the pubnub data outside the message callback? So I can assign it a variable name and use that to write to the database

Comment: This is a great idea! cool to see this.  To save the message data to your MySQL `database, you'd but the cursor.execute("INSERT INTO .. ")` and `database.commit()` inside the message receiver.

Answer (score 0):

## Saving Latitude Longitude Tracking Data to Database MySQL

The following example modifies the post from @Daiter123 original code sample.  The primary modification of the code is running **`cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ... ")`** and **`database.commit()`** inside the `message` receiver method defined in the `MySubscribeCallbackITF` class.

```
import os
import time
import sys
import datetime
import MySQLdb
from pubnub.enums import PNStatusCategory
from pubnub.callbacks import SubscribeCallback
from pubnub.pnconfiguration import PNConfiguration
from pubnub.pubnub import PubNub

pnconfig = PNConfiguration()
pnconfig.publish_key = "pub-c-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
pnconfig.subscribe_key = "sub-c-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
pubnub = PubNub(pnconfig)
 
CHANNEL = "frameData"
 
database = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="pi", passwd="raspberry", db="IoTProject")
cursor = database.cursor()

FrameID = 1
SerieNummer = "000001"
Longitude = ""
Latitude = ""
isGeladen = ""
Datum=datetime.datetime.now()
 
class MySubscribeCallbackITF(SubscribeCallback):
    def message (self, pubnub, message):
        if type(message.message) is list:
            Latitude    = message.message[0].lstrip("u")
            Longitude   = message.message[1].lstrip("u")
            Datum       = datetime.datetime.now()
            FrameID     = 1
            SerieNummer = "000001"

            print(Latitude)
            print(Longitude)

            ## =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
            ## Save Data to Database
            ## =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
            cursor.execute(
                "INSERT INTO IoTProject(FrameID,SerieNummer,isGeladen,Longitude,Latitude,Datum) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                (FrameID,SerieNummer,isGeladen,Longitude,Latitude,Datum))
            database.commit()
 
        elif type(message.message) is not list:
            isGeladen = message.message
            print(isGeladen)

        else:
            print("No data available")
 
    def status(self, pubnub, event):
        if event.category == PNStatusCategory.PNConnectedCategory:
            print("[STATUS: PNConnectedCategory]")
            print("connected to channels: " + CHANNEL)
 
print('Listening...')
pubnub.add_listener(MySubscribeCallbackITF())
pubnub.subscribe().channels(CHANNEL).execute()
```